# What does "Program type already present" mean?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to build an app in Android Studio.  After adding the Eclipse Paho library as a gradle dependency(or is it Maven?  I'm new to the Android ecosystem), I got the following error:

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

I've checked many different StackOverflow questions relating to this error, but the answers are all specific to certain libraries.  **I'm looking not only for a solution to the error, but an understanding of what the error *means*.**  That way it'll be easier for people to figure out solutions for their specific cases.  So far, no answer has provided that.

From other StackOverflow answers, I've gathered that it has something to do with my gradle file.  So, here's app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "---REDACTED FOR PRIVACY---"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.2'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2'
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/' }
}
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This problem usually come from a naming conflict, in your case the support-v4 library, which is use by several libraries.

To find the **list of dependencies** for the module `app` (default module's name for the app) we can do a `gradlew app:dependencies` to retrieve a list of all the libraries.

We found that `support-v4` is used by:

```
//short version of the dependencies list highlighting support-v4
+--- com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0

+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)

+--- org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2
|    +--- com.google.android:support-v4:r7  // <- problem here
```

We see that the support-v4 on Maps will use the version provided from support-v13.

We also see that the eclipse library is using another version (r7 ??).

To resolve your issue, you can try to exclude the module `support-v4` from this eclipse library like this:

```
implementation ('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Then you should be able to compile your application.

Btw you should take care that the eclipse module won't break by testing your code.

Comment: I had a different clash completely, but your answer has helped me actually GET the idea that something may clash. I've been using 2 different players that use Android Exo Player. May help someone some day. Thanks!

Comment: @Vucko How you have identified clash?

Comment: Through sheer luck. I started researching and noticed that my brightcove video player library uses exoplayer as it's dependency. Try to see what that could be for you.

Answer (score 105):

For me just **cleaning** the project solved the issue

Using **Terminal** :

```
./gradlew clean
```

Using **Android Studio** :

```
Build (menu) > Clean Project
```

Comment: Correct!Maybe it's android studio's bug.

Comment: In Android Studio can be done also from the menu `Build > Clean Project`.

Comment: For Android Studio `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and restart` may fix the issue as well

Comment: This answer doesn't explain what the error means, which is what the question is asking.

Comment: I wrote the answer many months later, just to share my experience with future readers .. they may look for long solutions and explanations, while it can be solved by one simple step .. @user2102929

Answer (score 15):

From [official Doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes)

If a class appears more than once on the runtime classpath, you get an error similar to the following:

`Program type already present com.example.MyClass`

This error typically occurs due to one of the following circumstances:

- A binary dependency includes a library that your app also includes as a direct dependency.

  For example, your app declares a direct dependency on Library A and Library B, but Library A already includes Library B in its binary.
  To resolve this issue, remove Library B as a direct dependency.
- Your app has a local binary dependency and a remote binary dependency on the same library.

  To resolve this issue, remove one of the binary dependencies.
  ( See if same library is added as jar and gradle dependency)

Comment: Thanks a lot. 1st one was the cause of issue for me. I used compileOnly for the repeated library that is inside another library, which the build will exclude when building.

Answer (score 4):

It's happened to me also but in my case, I try to include different dependencies that have same class using `debugApi` & `Api` so Android Studio marked as duplicate class, so I solved the issue by using `debugApi` & `releaseApi` to include different dependencies based on the build variant.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it mean I have 2 *.jar file or 2 libary some where in source code.
For example: I have 2 `youtube.jar` in `app/libary` and `module/libary`
Delete the redundant once and it will be fine

Comment: Yes! This one helped me!

Answer (score 2):

Add Support library to app level Gradle file

> implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'

Answer (score 1):

Problem for this issue - If you use the library as module & same library as dependency in another library.

Example: **LibraryA** imported as Module & same **LibraryA** added as dependency in any other library module.

How to fix this issue?

Solution 1 - > if you want to keep both -> Just refactor the package name of **LibraryA** module

Solution 2 - > remove the **LibraryA** dependency and use the module

> implementation project(':LibraryA')

Answer (score 1):

The reason I was getting this error was because I converted a Java file to a Kotlin one like this:

```
Code (menu) -> Convert Java file to Kotlin file
```

The old Java class must have still been hanging around on the classpath resulting in a duplicate. Doing a clean fixed it:

```
Build (menu) -> Clean Project
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps somebody,
a Build > Clean Project worked for me.

Comment: This solution has already been suggested in comments of another answer

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but with my project's internal library after updating from Android Studio 4.0.2 to 4.1. I have searched and tried many things without success. If you guys have the same case as me, I hope this answer can help. What I have done:

1. `Clean Project` then `Rebuild Project` - failed
2. `Invalidate Caches / Restart` - failed
3. Delete global Gradle caches (`/User/username/.gradle/caches` for macOS) - failed
4. Investigating app dependencies via terminal with the command: `./gradlew app:dependencies` **or** via Gradle tool window: `project->Tasks->android->androidDependencies` - nothing suspicious
5. Delete `.gradle` and `.idea` from my root project - success (although I'm not sure if I need to delete both. Maybe just delete one of them also working)