# RunTime Error while creating Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, authentication, build.gradle

**Here is my build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abhin.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

> **Runtime Error :**  Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior,
>   sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

Please guide where I am going wrong? Not able to create authentication UI.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Program type already present" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676155/what-does-program-type-already-present-mean)

Comment: No, it didn't resolve the issue

Comment: Please suggest what needs to be done