# How to build release apk after adding external library?

Tags: android, gradle, compilation, external

I added this videocompressor library https://github.com/fishwjy/VideoCompressor

I have to add a folder to my app and then I used `implementaion project(....);`, this method to add it to my app.
Now I couldn't create a release apk nor I can compile release apk.

[image: these are the errors i'm getting]

the program type already present error:

Program type already present:

```
org.aspectj.internal.lang.annotation.ajcDeclareAnnotation
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: org.aspectj.internal.lang.annotation.ajcDeclareAnnotation, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Can anyone please help as I'm unable to release my app anymore.

EDIT: i tried a lot of google searches and duplicate like questions but still the problem exists,**only if you're 100% sure of a question which is duplicate and which will solve my problem then only mark as duplicate.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Program type already present" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676155/what-does-program-type-already-present-mean)

Comment: 1. Copy error message. 2. Paste error message in Google. 3. Find duplicate. 4. Downvote and vote to close. Classic.

Comment: nope that didnt help my problem and the problem still exists

Answer (score 1):

Please execute this line on the android studio terminal:

```
 gradlew clean
```

and then go to file and click on sync project with Gradle files.

Comment: hey bro i did it and now my app is crashing each and every startup,its saying the reason is due to firebase pref something like that is not found, what can i do now the looks completely destroyed now 

Comment: oh never mind the problem was solved after editing the gradle of the external library but still now I'm unable to generate the release apk, same reason.