# Program type already present: org.apache.commons.codec.Decoder

Tags: android, apache, android-studio, gradle

I have been working on a project and recently added a lot of libraries. Then when I try to run the project, I am facing following error

> Program type already present: org.apache.commons.codec.Decoder

and I do not know to fix it. I searched many times but could not found same example with me.

Following is the app Gradle dependency list:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    implementation project(path: ':downloader_library')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

//    implementation 'com.javacodegeeks:slf4jconfig-javalogging:+'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.12'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'org.apache.commons') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '1.12'
            }
        }
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "26.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a lot of solutions like changing library version and adding resolution-strategy as mentioned in above grade code but still no solution.

Can you guys help me to fix the problem?

Thank you

Comment: maybe this answer can help you to identify the library in conflict: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49767860/6899896

Comment: have you already solved this? I have the same problem, I got this using the dependency 'org.apache.olingo:odata-client-core:4.5.0'

Comment: okay just an updat: I managed to do this by going to the link that @M.Ricciuti posted here, and tried the gradlew app:dependencies, then excluded the sub-dependency from the main dependency that I used.

Comment: So, basically no more error like yours is present on my side :)

Comment: I was facing the same error, but I had different dependencies. This is how I solved using the link previously provided: 
   `implementation('org.apache.poi:poi-scratchpad:3.9') {
        exclude module: 'commons-codec'
    }
    implementation('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.9') {
        exclude module: 'commons-codec'
    }
    implementation('org.apache.poi:poi:3.9') {
        exclude module: 'commons-codec'
    }`

Answer (score 1):

This problem is occurred from a naming conflict. In this case `org.apache.commons.codec.Decoder` is present in multiple libraries.
I also get this when I include the 
`Jwt auth0` library. What I did to over come is

```
Implementation('com.auth0:java-jwt:3.8.0'){
  exclude module: 'commons-codec'
}
```

What you have to do is exclude the `commons-codec` module when you include the new dependency.