# build:gradle:3.2.1: Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

Android Studio 3.2.1, Gradle 4.6.
Java 1.8

In `module1` I use in dir `libs/android-binding-v0.6-build718.jar`

It's containt class:

```
android\support\v4\accessibilityservice\AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl.class
```

in project/build.gradle:

```
  dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

in app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 421
        versionName "2.1.421"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

def AAVersion = '4.5.2'

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:ormlite:$AAVersion"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.1'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    implementation "org.androidannotations:ormlite-api:$AAVersion"

    implementation project(':module1')
    implementation project(':module2')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

here dependencies:

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:16.0.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1 (*)
```

But I get error:

```
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebugD8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: This answer might help you to understand & fix the problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49767860/6899896

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Not help. Same error.