# Library dependency not working with module

Tags: java, android

I'm using Android Studio. I have two modules: the app (UI) and a library. When tested separately, both compile and work as they should, but when I try to use some of the library classes on the app, I can't build the project. I get this error:

[image: Android Studio screenshot of failed build]

> Error: Program type already present: org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.Location

My library `build.gradle` has just a few lines:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'


dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.17'
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.17'

}

sourceCompatibility = "7"
targetCompatibility = "7"
```

Then my app's build.gradle is this

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "skrb.appprueba"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation project(path: ':coreLib')

}
```

When adding this (`implementation project(path: ':coreLib')`, I get the error and I don't know how to solve it.

Things that I tried:

- Cleaning and rebuilding the project.
- Setting *multiDexEnabled* to *true*

Comment: Looks like a naming or version conflict of the dependency `org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.Location`. Have look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49767860/3559908)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the error message, it should rather be:

```
implementation (project(path: ":coreLib")) {
    exclude group: "org.apache.xmlbeans"
}
```

Comment: Now getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Color;

Comment: @GuidoChia `xmlbeans` by itself has no dependencies (despite it should be already included in the package once); see for yourself: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/3.0.2 but you are actually using Java libraries in an Android project, which uses a subset of Java, which lacks some of the Java SE classes. therefore, you have to add the one absent class: https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/blob/master/poishadow/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/java/awt/Color.java (make sure the package name matches the expected one).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
implementation(project(path: ':coreLib')) {
    exclude module: 'poi'
    exclude module: 'poi-ooxml'
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676155/what-does-program-type-already-present-mean) you could find more information why this error happen.

Comment: Just tried and when trying to sync it says that it couldn't find method project() for arguments(...).

Comment: Edited, try one more time.

Comment: It builds now, thanks! Will try to run it on my device.

Comment: Excluding this modules results on the classes not workin. I'm getting ClassNotFoundException with the classes from the POI