# Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzst"

Tags: android, gradle

I was trying to upgrade my android compile and target version to 27 . But the dependencies always had issue . Currently the added dependencies looks like this but still some problem persists .

the dependencies in my gradle file looks like this.

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0'
```

I tried modifying the gradle dependencies but that isnt helping.
I want to upgrade the app gradle to version 27 but then still the problem persists.

Please help!

Comment: I had same issue, it was resolved by using same versions for Firebase dependencies.

Comment: i did that and new dependency issue is there. Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzel

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676155/what-does-program-type-already-present-mean/53592409