# AutoAnnotation error after updating to firebase-messaging:17.5.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Today I updated from:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
```

to:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0'
```

And I get this build error:

```
Error: Program type already present: com.google.auto.value.AutoAnnotation
```

All my other dependencies are up to date.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was google translate.

I did like Srikar suggested, just with translate. And used "exclude group". Like this:

```
implementation('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:0.5.0') {
    exclude group: 'io.grpc', module: 'grpc-all'
    exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
    exclude group: 'com.google.api-client', module: 'google-api-client-appengine'
    exclude group: 'com.google.auto.value'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is multiple dependencies are adding the library Auto Value creating a conflict.

Try to figure out which dependencies are adding the Auto Value library and remove them using `exclude` flag.

```
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0') {
    exclude module: 'com.google.auto.value'
}
```

For more info, take a look at a similar question -> [What does "Program type already present" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676155/what-does-program-type-already-present-mean/49767860)

Comment: Try `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` instead of `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging`

Comment: Didn't change anything