# Program type already present: com.android.common.constant.HttpConstants

Tags: android

I get this error :

```
{"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: com.android.common.constant.DbConstants","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
```

and I know there is a duplicate library in my project but I don't know witch library duplicated.

can some one help me?

Comment: Please add your `build.gradle` file

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49767860/6478047 once

Comment: thanks for answer but I can't find any dependency like "com.android.common.constant" in `gradlew app:dependencies `!! Can you help me to find it?

Comment: you have to remove 1 dependency at a time and see at what dependency the problem is solved .

Comment: or try adding
 `{
    exclude group: 'com.android.common'
} `
 ,below each dependency 1 at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run the command `gradlew app:dependencies` to check which dependency is getting repeated .
2. If you are unable to find out try removing 1 dependency at a time to check which dependency is causing the issue . after finding out the right dependency add 
   `{ exclude group: 'com.android.common' }` below that dependency
3. If you cannot remove dependencies then try adding `{ exclude group: 'com.android.common' }` below each dependency 1 at a time to find out which dependency is causing the issue .