# How to fix Error: Program type already present: jxl.CellView when importing jxl.jar library

Tags: android, jxl

I added jxl.jar library in order to be able to write and read excel files. But when I run the program I get one of these errors:

```
Error: Program type already present: jxl.CellView
Error: Program type already present: jxl.Booleancell
Error: Program type already present: jxl.DateCell
```

Before I added the jxl library the code was working so the porblem is likely in the gradle.
Before I used to get errors about different 'functions.properties' in the jxl.jar which I fixed by adding this

```
packagingOptions {

        exclude 'functions.properties'
        exclude 'functions_es.properties'
        exclude 'functions_nl.properties'
        exclude 'functions_en.properties'
        exclude 'functions_fr.properties'
        exclude 'functions_da.properties'
        exclude 'functions_de.properties'

    }
```

in `Android {}`, inside the gradle. I tried to do the same by adding

```
 exclude 'jxl/CellView'
 exclude 'jxl/BooleanCell'
 exclude 'jxl/dateCell'
```

inside the packagingOptions for the 'type already present' errors but it didn't work. How can I properly import this jxl library?

This is my entire gradle. Thanks in advance!

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.barxqrscanner2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {

        exclude 'functions.properties'
        exclude 'functions_es.properties'
        exclude 'functions_nl.properties'
        exclude 'functions_en.properties'
        exclude 'functions_fr.properties'
        exclude 'functions_da.properties'
        exclude 'functions_de.properties'
        exclude 'jxl/CellView'
        exclude 'jxl/BooleanCell'
        exclude 'jxl/dateCell'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/opencsv-4.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jxl.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Program type already present" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676155/what-does-program-type-already-present-mean)

Comment: Checked that one but it didn't solve the issue. Nothing from there helped since that error complains on android.support.v4. Mine complains on the files in the jxl folder inside the jxl.jar file or something in that direction