# Android: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app

Tags: android, react-native, android-support-library, androidx

I am getting below error when I tried to run Android project from React-Native. I removed the AndroidX support from the project.

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub
```

Dependancy:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
implementation project(':react-native-sentry')
implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
implementation project(':react-native-maps')
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.2"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.1"
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.3"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0"
```

I check the all the gradle version and everything, but nothing help me. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49767860/11212074

Comment: Can you please write which error is reported?

Comment: I got same error which I posted.

Answer (score 0):

> I removed the AndroidX support from the project.

It is **not correct** and it is the problem.
**Firebase migrated to AndroidX** in the latest release. It means that you are using both, support libraries and androidx libraries.

You can check the official [release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019); you are using these versions.

You can:

- migrate to androidx as described in the official doc
- downgrade your firebase dependencies