# Android - Firebase analytics causes failures

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Adding this line to my gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.1'
```

Results in this error:

```
error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
```

Based on what I read online, to fix this, I upgrade my compileSdkVersion from 27 to 28:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
```

Then I get this error when I try to run:

```
Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbq
```

And from there it's a spinning circle changing things and version numbers and adding things to the settings.gradle, etc, with androidx.  I have no idea how to fix this, and I imagine there is a more simple solution.  Thoughts?

EDIT: It may be worth mentioning that when I made the above changes, I see red across all of these, indicating that it should not use a different version (27) than the compileSdkVersion (28), so I'm not sure if I should make that change:

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportVersion"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I needed to go back to this version of Analytics for it to play nicely with my project:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.3'
```

The app compat libraries are not compatible with v17 or later of the analytics SDK, since it was migrated to androidx (androidx and the old v4 and v7 support libs are not compatible).  So in order to use the latest one, we would have to migrate all code to use androidx (which was not an option at this time).

Answer (score 0):

Well try to change to the latest version of firebase-analytics

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.1.0
```

And in your build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1
```

Comment: Yep, I tried that.  I get the following error:  Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub

Comment: Just tried that, and I get:  Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

Comment: Maybe you can try some of this step https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676155/what-does-program-type-already-present-mean

Comment: I tried that step of excluding it, but I still get the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Paste below lines in build.gradle (Module:app) may this help you:

```
    configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
      }
    }
```

This will force the build to use a lower support library.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately I get the same kind of error:  Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

Comment: Try invalidate caches/ restart

Comment: Yep, after every one of these changes, I typically do that.  Same error, though. :(