# Why does my flutter app doesn't compile when I download dependencies?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, androidx

I have a new flutter application (Nothing added or changed except following). I need to use these packages [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#-installing-tab-), [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler#-installing-tab-) and [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth#-installing-tab-). But as soon as I import these packages in my main.dart file *(after adding in pubsec.yaml)*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
```

It fails to compile and shows following error.

```
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
```

```
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver
```

```
BUILD FAILED in 7s
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See (this link will be in the comment) for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
*******************************************************************************************
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

What can I do to use all these three packages in same project. (I assumed it is because of androidX compatibility)

After adding following to gradlew.properties and setting compilerSdkVersion 28 in build gradle

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
..
```

Now I get following error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'androidx.core:core' has different version for the compile (1.0.0-rc01) and runtime (1.1.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
```

Comment: this is naming conflict.
please refer [Program type already present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676155/what-does-program-type-already-present-mean)

Comment: what can I do? @user5607081

Comment: you need to migrate your project to AndroidX. because packages have used AndroidX and you have used Support in gradle.

Comment: check [here](https://github.com/baseflowit/flutter-permission-handler#usage).

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya I solved issue using your link. Add this to answer so I can accept. Also add this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27254).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to migrate your project to AndroidX. because `permission_handler` package have used AndroidX and you have used Support libraries in gradle.

check [here](https://github.com/baseflowit/flutter-permission-handler#usage).

As @Kshitij Dhakal suggested, you need to also apply dependency resolution when version of same library is different in different packages.

Like, This solution is taken from [flutter issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27254).

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core' 
                       && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx')) {
                  details.useVersion "1.0.1"
            }
       }
    }    
}
```