# Program type already present: com.hlab.fabrevealmenu.model.FABMenuItem

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, compilation

I've been receiving the following error whenever i try to "Generate Signed Bundle / Apk" in android studio : `Program type already present: com.hlab.fabrevealmenu.model.FABMenuItem`
The app works perfectly when i run it with android studio on my smartphone or on the emulator.

this is my `Build.gradle (Module app)`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mtp.laboproject"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://picking-geant.ddns.net:84/\""
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    def cor_version = "1.3.2"
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0-rc02"
    def retrofit_version = "2.6.0"
    def work_version = "2.2.0"
    def anko_version = '0.10.8'
    def dispatcher_version = '4.6.0'
    def rxJavaVersion = '2.0.1'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'

    // Kotlin + coroutines + RX
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxJavaVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //bind view
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'


//    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"


    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0'

    //Kodein Dependency Injection
    implementation "org.kodein.di:kodein-di-generic-jvm:6.3.2"
    implementation "org.kodein.di:kodein-di-framework-android-x:6.3.2"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0"

    // Json to/from Object
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.8.+'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'

    // set biometric bio
    implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$cor_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$cor_version"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta02'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'

    //dagger support    
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"

    implementation "org.permissionsdispatcher:permissionsdispatcher:$dispatcher_version"
    kapt "org.permissionsdispatcher:permissionsdispatcher-processor:$dispatcher_version"

    implementation 'com.scottyab:secure-preferences-lib:0.1.7'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'

    //ExiInterface from androidx
    implementation "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.1.0"

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'

    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
    implementation project(':fabrevealmenu')


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this is my `Build.gradle (Module fabrevealmenu)`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0.4"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
 //   implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    //External libs
    implementation 'com.github.asyl.animation:arcanimator:1.0.0'

}

ext {
    PUBLISH_GROUP_ID = 'com.hlab.fabrevealmenu'
    PUBLISH_ARTIFACT_ID = 'fab-reveal-menu'
    PUBLISH_VERSION = '1.0.4'
}
```

I should also note that i have tried some of the suggested solutions in other topics but they didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676155/what-does-program-type-already-present-mean

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Program type already present" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676155/what-does-program-type-already-present-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved.
The project isn't mine, there actually was a library that was made as a second project, and a file of it was created inside the main project. All had to do was to remove the file in main project and add "import" to second project.
Thank you all