# Program type already present: dagger.Binds

Tags: android, gradle, dagger-2

I am getting **Program type already present: dagger.Binds** while building my app.

In my project I have 2 modules **mod1, mod2**

mod1 - depends on common-release-1.0.5.0.aar(its using dagger-2.7.jar internally): *compile(name: 'common-release-1.0.5.0', ext: 'aar')*

mod2 - it has a direct dagger dependency(*implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.23'*) and also depends on mod1(*implementation project(':mod1')*)

As I can't change the .aar file how to resolve this situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Program type already present" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676155/what-does-program-type-already-present-mean)

Comment: no, but it definitely gives some hint, the problem here is the .aar file which internally using dagger