# How to access the Java classes and methods of a local .jar file from kotlin code in flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin

I have create a flutter plugin and I want to use a local .aar file in it. my project structure (the android part) looks like this:

```
--android
  --gradle
  --libs
    --geth.jar
  --src
    --main
      --Kotlin code
  --build.gradle
```

so to use a .aar file in my plugin, first I have downloaded the geth .aar file from this link:

https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/

then I have changed the name to geth.jar (please note the change in format just by changing name) then I have imported it into the project by creating a libs folder in the android folder of the plugin:

```
--android
  --gradle
  --libs <--!! here
    --geth.jar
  --src
    --main
      --Kotlin code
  --build.gradle
```

and then at the end of the build.graadle file at the dependencies section, I haave cchanged it to this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) <--!! this part was added

}
```

now, my question is how can I use this .aar (or .jar) file's classes and methods inside the kotlin file of android? which is here:
--android
--gradle
--libs
--geth.jar
--src
--main
--Kotlin code <--!!here
--build.gradle
I have tried this but it gives error:

```
package com.example.flutter

import androidx.annotation.NonNull

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar
import go.geth.gojni.Account; <--!! this is added
import go.geth.gojni.Geth; <--!! this is added
import go.geth.gojni.KeyStore; <--!! this is added
import go.geth.gojni.Node; <--!! this is added
import go.geth.gojni.NodeConfig; <--!! this is added


/** FlutterNPlugin */
class FlutterNPlugin: FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {
  /// The MethodChannel that will the communication between Flutter and native Android
  ///
  /// This local reference serves to register the plugin with the Flutter Engine and unregister it
  /// when the Flutter Engine is detached from the Activity
  private lateinit var channel : MethodChannel

  override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, "flutter")
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)
  }

  override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
    if (call.method == "getPlatformVersion") {
      NodeConfig nc = new NodeConfig();
      result.success("Android ${android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE}")
    } else {
      result.notImplemented()
    }
  }

  override fun onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(null)
  }
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @fartem
Classifier 'NodeConfig' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not valid Kotlin syntax, try to replace this:

```java
NodeConfig nc = new NodeConfig();
```

by this:

```kotlin
val nc = NodeConfig()
```

Comment: it is now giving this error: 
D8: Program type already present: go.Seq$GoObject
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
Program type already present: go.Seq$GoObject

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676155/what-does-program-type-already-present-mean